# Bug - pushing SharedPreference data to backend by JSON Object

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am getting strange values at times, regardless of what I enter.
[image: Backend screenshot]

Note: "null" is actually a String I have set as default

**Code where I save in SharedPreference**

```
        billText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billNumber);
        tableNumberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tableNumber);
        amountText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        remarksText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remarks);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SharedPreference.Form.FORM, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tableNumberText.getText().toString() != null || tableNumberText.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editor.putString(SharedPreference.Form.TABLE_NUMBER, tableNumberText.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if (amountText.getText().toString() != null || amountText.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editor.putString(SharedPreference.Form.AMOUNT, amountText.getText().toString());
                }

                if (billText.getText().toString() != null || billText.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editor.putString(SharedPreference.Form.BILL_NUMBER, billText.getText().toString());
                }

                if (remarksText.getText().toString() != null || remarksText.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editor.putString(SharedPreference.Form.REMARKS, remarksText.getText().toString());
                }

                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedbackActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

**Code where I push the data**

```
                    jsonObj.put("bill", sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreference.Form.BILL_NUMBER, "null"));
                    jsonObj.put("table", sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreference.Form.TABLE_NUMBER, "null"));
                    jsonObj.put("amount", sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreference.Form.AMOUNT, "null"));
                    jsonObj.put("remarks", sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPreference.Form.REMARKS, "null"));
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
```

**Edit**:

**What I intend to do**: Persist data through SharedPreference. I first save data through an Activity (first block of code), then I push the data to the backend. There are four Text fields (`EditText`) from where I get `String` data.

**Expected behavior**: When I use method

`jsonObj.put("key", SharedPreference.getString(key, default-value)`

I should get the value I had saved in the Activity put at the backend.

**Result**:

At the backend, rather than getting what I enter, I get what is shown in the screenshot.

**Strange part**: Though, as you can see, the code is same for all four fields have the same code (there are four `EditText` fields where the user enters the data) three of them get default-string, i.e. `"null"` and one (Amount) stays blank.

**PS**: In all these tests that I run, I never left all the fields blank.

Comment: at first call `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(tableNumberText.getText().toString()))` instead of `if (tableNumberText.getText().toString() != null || tableNumberText.getText().toString() != "")`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, it didn't solve the bug. I tried.

Comment: what strange ??... add more details to ur question... first of all it always let you put the spaces on edittexts.. according to your current code.

Comment: @SRBbans if you look at the screenshot of the database at the backend, you can see that when the bug appears, three fields get the data that is there in default String, i.e. `"null"`, while one field is always blank. **always**, regardless of which fields I leave empty, even though the code for all of them is same. That, is the **strange** part.

Comment: okey ..... but you should try to put that `edit()` and `commit()` just before and after the sharedpref operations.. like in `onClick`.,, and take care of the Keys you provided for the values.... and do a proper research around your code before calling it a `BUG`.

Comment: @SRBbans, please observe the values in the screenshot in my question. Please notice that a lot of times three fields have value "null" and one field is blank. That is strange because the code for all of them is same. And it is also strange that sometimes I do get values there, as you can see in the screenshot and at other times I don't. Code, screenshot both are provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to test if an EditText is currently empty is:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(amountText.getText())) {...}
```

Comment: This did not solve the bug. The issue is persisting.

Comment: You did not describe the actual issue, beside saying the result is "strange". Please give more info about the expected and current behavior.

Comment: Please read the added details (from **Edit**). Thanks for the help.